amplify_flutter dependency breaks build
I'm completely new to flutter and all the concepts behind building android apps. So I thought I'd follow the budget_tracker tutorial: https://docs.amplify.aws/flutter/start/getting-started/setup/
After running flutter create budget_tracker and adding all the dependencies to my pubspec.yaml (no reason to copy/paste, please check link for context), I ran flutter run against flutter-emulator (android-arm64 emulator)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':amplify_secure_storage:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
Could not determine the dependencies of null.
Cannot query the value of this provider because it has no value available.

I thought, oh right, might need to do additional setup before it works, so headed to the Platform setup [Android] section (again, check link for reference), and mimicked the setup, then ran flutter run  again I get this;
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file '/Users/******/code/personal/budget_tracker/android/build.gradle' line: 21

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

If I nuke everything and start fresh with flutter create budget_tracker it has no problems running in the emulator, but as soon as I add amplify_flutter everything goes boom.
I've tried the versions listed in the guide (^1.0.0) as well as 1.6.0, and 1.8.0 but I just can't get it to work.
Anyone who's been able to get passed this?
This is my flutter doctor output (omitting irrelevant data)
✅ Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on macOS 14.3 23D56 darwin-arm64)
✅ Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
✅ Android Studio (version 2023.2)
✅ VS Code (version 1.88.1)
✅ Network resources

I've tried this tutorial as well:
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-flutter-mobile-app-part-one/module-two/
And it goes boom as soon as I try to run it as well (same as the first issue in this post but for another aws package)
bump versions, follow official tutorial, upgrade android studio
EDIT: add android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

the above is the build.gradle without the changes stated in the tutorial - gives me the first error
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}

the above is the build.gradle WITH the changes stated in the tutorial - gives. me the second error
Edit: added android/app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.budget_tracker"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.budget_tracker"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}


try searching for the exact error here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues

@Jain have tried doing that, but haven't found anything

please share contents of your build.gradle file

@Jain added via edit to original question

is this all content?
this should be inside the buildscript block
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
repositories {}
}

that is the complete android/build.gradle.
I've added android/app/build.gradle now as well
